# Custom filters - how to show only questions with answers

Tags: feature-request, custom-filter

Saving custom filters is a nice feature. But unfortunately I can't configure it in a way that it only shows questions with answers (either accepted or not accepted).

[image]

- Missing:
  Filter by **answered** questions (whether accepted or not accepted)

Can you add this function to the filter criteria?

---

NOTE: For example, like the "Tagged with" option allows to enter "The following tags:", there could be a field for the [search keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/search) to specify "answers:1" for 1+ answers or a lot more, making it really powerful!

Comment: I am very curious what you would use the filter for. I can't think of a single use this might have.

Comment: Simple answer - oftentimes I am using Stackoverflow to find solutions for issues I have. Then it is of course useful, if you're looking for questions with answers. Sometimes it doesn't help to look for questions only. 
@Gimby - for what purpose are you using Stackoverflow? Questions and answers, right?

Comment: Looking for unanswered question and answer them is one query I am using. This is the opposite query - looking for questions with answers and search within to find answers quickly. That is the single use I want it for.

Comment: From my experience, when searching for solutions to a specific issue, I've found that Google gives better results than Stack Overflow's built-in search.

Comment: @DonaldDuck - that's another story, but yes you are right - lol   :-D